# Untick Step over properties and operators doesn't work

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-2015

All I want is not to hit the getter and the setter of each property every time I step through the code.
So I unticked the highlighted options in the picture below, restarted VS, and tried again, it stills steps through the getter and the setter of all properties, why? I want to avoid that, any thoughts?

[image]

EDIT:

Enabling or disabling the option *Step over properties and operators*, makes no difference, it still hits the getter and the setter

Comment: If you want it to step OVER them as opposed to INTO them, the first of those checkboxes should be checked, surely?

Comment: Of course, english is not my first language, so sometimes I fail to understand these things

Comment: Enabling it makes no difference

Comment: @Tuco,Would you mind sharing us the complete code in your side? As I tested it with VS2015 and VS2017  to debug it, they both work fine. I mean that enable that option would not step into get/set property. Please test it using other VS version in your side. Or make sure that you use the latest VS update for your VS. Reset your VS settings, and then create a new project, debug it again with/without that option.

Comment: @Tuco, Any update for this issue? If you get any latest information, please feel free to share it here.

Comment: "Reset your VS settings, and then create a new project, debug it again with/without that option" This worked! Thanks @JackZhai-MSFT

Comment: @Tuco, Since this issue has been resolved, I add the solution as an answer, if possible, you could mark it as the answer, so it can help other community members. Have a nice day:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it worked well in our side, we would think about whether it is related to certain debug settings.

We often use the default settings, and then create a new project and view the result, so reset the VS settings would be a path for this issue.